# Python Tkinter freezes on Button click

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, freeze

I'm Using this code snippet in my tkinter project 
and it freezes immediately when I press the button.
How can I prevent it from freezing?

```html
# Toggle Button
def toggle():
    if t_btn.config('text')[-1] == 'ON':
        t_btn.config(text='OFF')
        cmd = os.system('python test.py')
    #    cmd = 'python net_stat.py'
        op = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
        list1.insert(Tk.END, op)

    else:
        t_btn.config(text='ON')
        r.quit()

t_btn = Tk.Button(page1, text="ON", width=12, command=toggle)
t_btn.pack(side=Tk.BOTTOM)
```

Comment: 1st you do not want to use `config()` to check the text. Use `t_btn['text'] == 'ON'` instead. If you place a print statement before each line in your toggle function you can find out where the application is getting stuck.

Comment: i did what u said and it is Compilig untill cmd = os.system but its not adding element in list view in tkinter. showing the output in command shell but GUI freezes i dont know why

Comment: Likely because your os.system command is blocking the main loop. You may want to run that in its own thread.

Answer (score -1):

It might be because when you are pressing the button, you are running another file when you press the button (You are calling os.system('python test.py') which is running a python file)

Comment: But that step is important I need that file to run on button click

Comment: What are the contents of test.py?

Comment: It outputs packet information like packet size , source IP , destination ip etc

Comment: Hmm, the only thing that I can think of is that there is a while loop in that script that is never-ending, or your network is slow and it is causing it to freeze, but I have never dealt with any network stuff in python except for sockets, so I am afraid I can't help you with that, sorry.

Comment: Yes there is while loop and this issue is bugging me for long time now , it'll be okay even if you have some references for me

Comment: Could you put the script in a repl.it project so I can see what the code is for test.py?